# What is the proper integration technique for this equation?

Tags: integration

I'm trying to integrate $\int \frac{v^3}{v^4 + 1} dv$.  What is the proper technique or formula to use for this?

I don't need (or want) the answer.  Just an approach.

Comment: u substitution.

Comment: The antiderivate is $\frac{ln(v^4+1)}{4}$

Comment: I see.  It's $\int \frac {du}{u}$

Answer (score 1):

Note that the numerator is the derivative of the denominator. That is always the first thing one should check.